# Where can I find documentation for the "miktex-hunspell" package?

Tags: packages

Does the miktex package "miktex-hunspell"  have a documentation file? If so, how do I obtain it?

Comment: Searching the MikTex site leads to the dll file. Seems to not have a documentation file, but one could ask the people at MikTex.